# How to use hard disk with raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, solid-state-drive

I have a raspberry pi Zero and I wnat to use a 128GB ssd hard disk with it. How can I connect it to my raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also be aware about this kickstarter project: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/2073955313/pidrive-low-power-msata-ssd-for-the-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 0):

Use a USB HDD enclosure.
[Google](https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=usb%20hdd%20enclosure&oq=usb%20hdd%20enclosure&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4920j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)